# sp_MSforeachdb issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to assign VIEW DEFINITION access for stored procedures in an environment at work for developers and run the query below as Result to Text then copy the output and run as Result to Grid:

```
select 'GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON ' + quotename(specific_schema) 
+ '.' + quotename(specific_name)
+ ' TO ' + 'TestAcct'
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.routines
where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

The problem I have is that I have to do this against each and every database on multiple servers.  I have tried to run it with 'sp_MSforeachdb' but when I setup the query it doesn't like my select statement.  Any ideas on how to format the above query for all DBs so that I can copy the output and run it against a server instead of each individual DB?

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 
'SELECT ''GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON '' + quotename(''?'') + ''.'' + quotename(specific_schema) 
+ ''.'' + quotename(specific_name)
+ '' TO '' + ''TestAcct'' AS ''?''
FROM ?.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.routines
WHERE routine_type = ''PROCEDURE'''
```

Comment: I thought this would work, however it creates a very peculiar issue.  Whatever DB is selected in SSMS from the dropdown box, when you run it, it returns the same stored procs on that DB for all DBs.  For example: If run against master it outputs GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON test.[dbo].[sp_MSrepl_startup] TO TestAcct
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON test.[dbo].[sp_MScleanupmergepublisher] TO TestAcct
for every DB rather than the SPs that should be on each DB

Comment: it returns only those procedures, which contains on that particular DB in DB loop.Try now @Sheddy. This correct answer..

Answer (score 1):

If you're just going to let your test account view the definition of whatever, why not:

```
grant view definition to [TestAccount]
```

That way, it stays current when you create new objects within the database. Simpler solution that works better, in my opinion.

Comment: I really like this method! However when I adapted it to using p_mforeachdb it again says completed successfully, but only applies the change for the DB in the dropdown box and doesn't actually do it 'for each DB'.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. sp_msforeachdb doesn't change database context. What I typically do is have the sp_msforeachdb print the right statements and then execute them in another window. Something like "exec sp_msforeachdb 'print ''use [?];grant view definition to [TestAccount];'''. You may be able to get away without the print (the use putting you in the right context), but this will work for sure.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely will work.  I'd like it to be refined even more, but it will be fairly quick and efficient.